Batch job not running Window Task Scheduler
My batch job file is a wrapper for a python script. The python script will go to a url and post some message in the forum using selenium.
It works when I checked 'run when user is logged on' but when I select 'run whether the user is logged in or not', i will receive a 0x1 error. I understand the latter does not work for interactive task. Is my use case considered interactive?
Thanks.

I would move this question to serverfault.com. This question seems to cover your question in great detail: https://serverfault.com/questions/734035/running-a-batch-file-from-task-scheduler-without-user-being-logged-in
